# .net executable build on xp, does not start on windows 7 - werfault

Tags: .net, windows, deployment, windows-7

i've made a .NET application on an Windows XP workstation and it works fine.
But if i try to run it on Windows 7 the application does not start at all - no windows, no error messages, nothing visibile. I've tryed in every combination of compatibility mode in 7 but no one works.
The only thing i can see in task manager is that when i start the application on windows 7 at the same time the werfault.exe process is started, then after a few seconds both disappears.

Is there a werfault.exe log file or something to check to understand what is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try looking at the Windows Event Log. It might contain information about the error. Also try running as administrator. You should also make sure that the correct .NET framework is installed on the Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Thanks! I do not know why I did not think about it! In the Event Log i've found the exception. It is a .NET 4.0 behaviour to not show -unhandled- exceptions with message boxes?

Comment: @Valerio Manfredi, it depends on the exception, the type of application, whether there is some exception handling in your code, when this exception occurs, etc...

Comment: in this case was a "Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException", and the application is a simple Windows Forms application.

Comment: @Valerio Manfredi, when does this exception occur? At which point of the execution of the application?

Comment: @Valerio Manfredi, I suspect that this is the reason why you don't see any message boxes. The main window is not even created as the constructor throws.

Comment: @Valerio try using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) to determine which file is not found. (Process Monitor should be part of *every* developers basic toolkit on Windows.)

Comment: Yes, i've already done and the problem was missing Sql Server CE 3.5 dll missing on Windows 7. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Be patient, and learn from the experts, :)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/06/05/setting-net-breakpoints-in-windbg-for-applications-that-crash-on-startup.aspx

A lower level debugger such as WinDbg can help in most toughest times.

In your case, an unhandled exception occurred, and WinDbg + SOS can show you the exception details, if you run !pe.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The default project template for WinForms is missing a couple of try/catch blocks that it really should have to avoid these kinds of problems.

The form  constructor is a simple

```
InitializeComponent();
```

Better to have a try/catch block around that throws up a messagebox showing the error.

The same for Main in Program.cs

I have occasionally had problems displaying a messagebox when erroring in these methods so I resort to displaying a console window:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

Then call:

```
string msg = "Some explanation.";
AllocConsole();
Console.WriteLine(msg);
MessageBox.Show(msg);
```